# What Linux tool will tell me if all the mounted disks share roughly the same bandwidth?

Tags: linux, performance, io

What Linux tool will tell me if all the mounted disks share roughly the same bandwidth? Can I do something like iostat for each of my /dev/sd* devices?

Comment: Question is unclear.  What do you mean by "share roughly the same bandwidth"?  Are you trying to figure out if they are each capable of about the same sequential throughput, or if attempting to access both at the same time will result in less throughput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you may use iostat with '-d'

```
# iostat -d 1
```

2) vmstat -p /dev/sdaX shows detailed statistics for some partition

```
# vmstat -p /dev/sda1
```

Comment: `iostat -x -m 5`  is very helpful in diagnosing if you have one disk that' under-performing.  -x gives you extra details about each disk, and you get to see each disk separately.  Extra useful when you got software RAID, as you can look at your array as parts (disks), and as the whole (the RAID device).